# how do i validate the date fomat as input(MM/DD/YYYY) as valid,invalid and null with out using any functions in pl/sql(by using only if else)

Tags: sql, oracle, date

--inputdate should be in the format of 'mm/dd/yyyy' which i needs to convert it to only 'mm/yyyy'

```
procedure validatedate(inputdate date)

declare
l_tmpdate varchar2(20);

BEGIN

  if inputdate is NOT NULL then
   BEGIN
   l_tmpdate:=to_char(inputdate ,'mm/yyyy');
   end;
   else
     dbms_output.put_line('Mandatory input should be given--Date should not be NULL');
     RAISE application_error;
```

//How to perform if the date is invalid i.e., if the date format is received other than mm/dd/yyyy format
it has to give the msg like "Invalid input is given".

```
   raise error;
```

Comment: Input validation is easier to handle at the application level.

Comment: How do you validate `11/12/2013`? this could be either `11th of December` *or* `12th of November`. Both are valid dates.

Comment: @kaf:you are right..I agree with you..

Comment: with this date format you can not validate. either allow user to chose month,date, and year secretly on UI. (like individual drop boxes ) that makes sure date is in expected format. or get the input in the CHAR format. for example November 12 2013" only in this cases you need separate function to validate Date. i prefer the the first one.

Comment: @AnupShah:In the table the value stored as 6/19/2007 10:05:00AM(mm/dd/yyyy format) which  i can convert it to dd/mm/yyyy right..?

Answer (score 2):

Since your parameter `inputdate` is a `date` already, it can't be invalid<sup>*</sup>. You said:

> In the table the value stored as 6/19/2007 10:05:00AM(mm/dd/yyyy format)

Dates are stored [internally as numbers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/tablecls.htm#CNCPT413), they are not formatted. When you query your table for a `date` value the client retrieves that internal representation and converts it to a string based on its settings or your NLS_DATE_FORMAT, giving you something recognisable.

In your procedure you are calling `to_char(input_date)`, which will always be working on a valid date, so there is nothing for you to check. But as you don't use `l_tempdate` it seems like a pointless check.

It would be a different matter if you were passing a string into a procedure and converting that to a date. Then you would need to allow for and handle invalid inputs, unless you knew you could guarantee you were always going to be passed valid values - if it's only ever called from an application layer that did the validation, for example. Nothing is foolproof though.

<sub><sup>*</sup> Well, usually; it's possible to create invalid dates but it's hard work, and almost certainly not something you need to worry about here.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You don't receive any date format. You receive a date, which is either a valid date or NULL by definition. No need to check anything (except for NULL, if you want so). You can display a date in any format you like, be it 'mm/yyyy' or anything else.